# Why do I get org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate id generator?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Why do I get

> Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate id generator [entity-name=hw11.model.domain.Client]?

[Here](https://github.com/Partizanin/taxi-service/blob/8366f8510f44b4486f3e1c0822786b6731ef7f1b/src/main/java/hw11/model/domain/Client.java#L24-L24) is class Client here the class in which an error

Comment: Would you mind narrowing the problem down? As it is it's a whole lot of work to tell anything

Comment: I'm just looking to solve this problem.

Comment: Please delete the existing sequence and make sequence is auto

Answer (score 14):

My code was like that:

```
...
@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "stu_seq", sequenceName = "STUDENT_SEQ", allocationSize = 10)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "stu_seq")
private int id;
...
```

I just set the `allocationSize` as 1 and solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

It says everything you need to know:

```
org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect does not support sequences
```

Do not use sequence when you're using MySQL. You probably have some entities that have a `id` definition like this:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "your_seq")
private Long id;
```

Replace them with following code in order to use MySQL's `Auto Increment` feature:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
```

Comment: thank you all already figured out the problem!
The problem was that before the project was started with a data base Oracle, and now with Mysql here and there a conflict!

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that before the project was started with a Oracle database, and now with MySQL here and there a conflict.